# @react-native-firebase/crashlytics does not give exact file name for the crash

Tags: firebase, react-native, crashlytics, react-native-firebase

I was trying to work with @react-native-firebase/crashlytics. I can see crash issue(not very much readable) but I cannot see the exact javascipt file name of that crash in the firebase console.

Is it even possible to get the exact filename of the issue in crashlytics ??
I followed every step of documentation for crashlytics.

Crashlytics().crash() is showing in console, that means setup is properly done. It's just that it is not showing the file name. It is only showing Main Activity